# Grep for a word and then grep the next occurring word

Tags: shell, grep

I would like to `grep` a word. Then, I would like to print the next matching line.

Ex: Input file

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
BBBB
CCCC
EEEE
AAAA
WWWW
CCCC
```

Output

```
AAAA                        
CCCC              
AAAA  
CCCC
```

I would want to search for `AAAA` first every time and then print the first line with `CCCC` after it. Please help by using `grep` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer for Revised Question

Using this as the sample file:

```
$ cat file2
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
BBBB
CCCC
EEEE
AAAA
WWWW
CCCC
```

To print every line containing `AAAA` followed by the first line after it that contains `CCCC`, use:

```
$ sed -n '/AAAA/,/CCCC/ {/AAAA/p;/CCCC/p}' file2
AAAA
CCCC
AAAA
CCCC
```

#### Answer for Original Question

> "I would want to search for AAAA first and then print the first line with CCCC after it."

Using this as the sample file:

```
$ cat file
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
BBBB
CCCC
EEEE
```

To match the first line containing `CCCC` that occurs after the first line containing `AAAA`:

```
$ sed -n '/AAAA/,$ {/CCCC/{p;q}}' file
CCCC
```

How it works:

- `-n`

  This tells `sed` not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `/AAAA/,$ {/CCCC/{p;q}}`

  `/AAAA/,$` is a range.  It specifies that the commands that follow it in braces are executed only if we between a line that matches `AAAA` and the last line in the file, denoted `$`.

  `/CCCC/` is another condition.  It tells `sed` to execute the commands which follow only if we are on a line that matches `CCCC`.

  `{p;q}` is a group of two commands.  `p` tells `sed` to print the current line.  `q` tells `sed` to quit (so no further lines will be read or matched).

Comment: Thanks John. I have added more requirements to the question. Can you help me doing the same with grep? Thanks.